# JS - Intercept attribute changes

Tags: javascript

My goal here is to intercept all attribute setting and changes. Problem is that I don't know how to do that. I wanna change attributes that set / change like this
`cpo.src = "/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/orchestrate/jsch/v1";` not using `setAttribute(src, 'stufz')`
I have some code that could be used from my Ajax interceptor that works 100% and changes the request. Basically why I am doing this is I am making a web proxy and it needs great rewriting. Please client-side JS only! Pure Javascript too!

Basically heres an example of how I wanna intercept it

`/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/orchestrate/jsch/v1` --> `/alloy?url=https://soap2day.to/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/orchestrate/jsch/v1`

If I am not being clear enough please explain in the comments.

````
// Ajax Interceptor that works perfectly that could be used in this case.

let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

   if (url.startsWith('http')) {
   const encodedURL = btoa(url)
   url = '/alloy/?url=' + encodedURL
   } else if (url.startsWith('//')) {
         const encodedURL = btoa('http:'  + url)
         url = '/alloy/?url=' + encodedURL
   } else if (url.startsWith('/')) {
      if (!url.startsWith('/fetch/')) {
         let apData = document.getElementById('alloyData');
         let urlData = apData.getAttribute('data-alloyURL');
         url = '/fetch/' + urlData + url
      }
   }

    return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
   }```
````

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#Example) if you want to monitor HTML.

Comment: Or a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) ?